# Copying bytes in Python from Numpy array into string or bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, buffer

I am reading data from an UDP socket in a while loop.  I need the most efficient way to

1) Read the data (*) (that's kind of solved, but comments are appreciated)

2) Dump the (manipulated) data periodically in a file (**) (The Question)

I am anticipating a bottleneck in the numpy's "tostring" method.  Let's consider the following piece of (an incomplete) code:

```
import socket
import numpy

nbuf=4096
buf=numpy.zeros(nbuf,dtype=numpy.uint8) # i.e., an array of bytes
f=open('dump.data','w')

datasocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# ETC.. (code missing here) .. the datasocket is, of course, non-blocking

while True:
  gotsome=True
  try:
    N=datasocket.recv_into(buf) # no memory-allocation here .. (*)
  except(socket.error):
    # do nothing ..
    gotsome=False

  if (gotsome):
    # the bytes in "buf" will be manipulated in various ways ..
    # the following write is done frequently (not necessarily in each pass of the while loop):
    f.write(buf[:N].tostring())  # (**) The question: what is the most efficient way to do this?

f.close()
```

Now, at (**), as I understand it:

1) buf[:N] allocates memory for a new array object, having the length N+1, right? (maybe not)

.. and after that:

2) buf[:N].tostring() allocates memory for a new string, and the bytes from buf are copied into this string

That seems a lot of memory-allocation & swapping.  In this same loop, in the future, I will read several sockets and write into several files.

Is there a way to just tell f.write to access directly the memory address of "buf" from 0 to N bytes and write them onto the disk?

I.e., to do this in the spirit of the buffer interface and avoid those two extra memory allocations?

P. S. f.write(buf[:N].tostring()) is equivalent to buf[:N].tofile(f)

Comment: Have you profiled your code? I could imagine that a bit of extra allocation does not hurt much when writing to a file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, it sounds like you want to use the array's `tofile` method or directly use the `ndarray.data` buffer object.

For your exact use-case, using the array's `data` buffer is the most efficient, but there are a lot of caveats that you need to be aware of for general use.  I'll elaborate in a bit.

---

However, first let me answer a couple of your questions and provide a bit of clarification:

> `buf[:N]` allocates memory for a new array object, having the length N+1, right?

It depends on what you mean by "new array object".  Very little additional memory is allocated, regardless of the size of the arrays involved.

It does allocate memory for a new array object (a few bytes), but it *does not* allocate additional memory for the array's data.  Instead, it creates a "view" that shares the original array's data buffer.  Any changes you make to `y = buf[:N]` will affect `buf` as well.

> buf[:N].tostring() allocates memory for a new string, and the bytes from buf are copied into this string

Yes, that's correct.

On a side note, you can actually go the opposite way (string to array) without allocating any additional memory:

```
somestring = 'This could be a big string'
arr = np.frombuffer(buffer(somestring), dtype=np.uint8)
```

However, because python strings are immutable, `arr` will be read-only.

---

> Is there a way to just tell f.write to access directly the memory address of "buf" from 0 to N bytes and write them onto the disk?

Yep!

Basically, you'd want:

```
f.write(buf[:N].data)
```

This is very efficient and will work for any file-like object. It's almost definitely what you want in this exact case.  However, there are several caveats!

First off, note that `N` will be in items in the array, not in bytes directly. They're equivalent in your example code (due to `dtype=np.int8`, or any other 8-bit datatype).

If you did want to write a number of bytes, you could do

```
f.write(buf.data[:N])
```

...but slicing the `arr.data` buffer will allocate a new string, so it's functionally similar to `buf[:N].tostring()`.  At any rate, be aware that doing `f.write(buf[:N].tostring())` is different than doing `f.write(buf.data[:N])` for most dtypes, but both will allocate a new string.

Next, numpy arrays can share data buffers.  In your example case, you don't need to worry about this, but in general, using `somearr.data` can lead to surprises for this reason.

As an example:

```
x = np.arange(10, dtype=np.uint8)
y = x[::2]
```

Now, `y` shares the same memory buffer as `x`, but it's not contiguous in memory (have a look at `x.flags` vs `y.flags`). Instead it references *every other* item in `x`'s memory buffer (compare `x.strides` to `y.strides`).

If we try to access `y.data`, we'll get an error telling us that this is not a contiguous array in memory, and we can't get a single-segment buffer for it:

```
In [5]: y.data
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-364eeabf8187> in <module>()
----> 1 y.data

AttributeError: cannot get single-segment buffer for discontiguous array
```

---

This is a large part of the reason that numpy array's have a `tofile` method (it also pre-dates python's `buffer`s, but that's another story).

`tofile` will write the data in the array to a file without allocating additional memory.  However, because it's implemented at the C-level it only works for real `file` objects, not file-like objects (e.g. a socket, StringIO, etc).

For example:

```
buf[:N].tofile(f)
```

However, this is implemented at the C-level, and *will only work for actual file objects*, not sockets, StringIO, and other file-like objects.

This does allow you to use arbitrary array indexing, however.

```
buf[someslice].tofile(f)
```

Will make a new view (same memory buffer), and efficiently write it to disk.  In your exact case, it will be slightly slower than slicing the `arr.data` buffer and directly writing it to disk.
If you'd prefer to use array indexing (and not number of bytes) then the `ndarray.tofile` method will be more efficient than `f.write(arr.tostring())`.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer.  That's about it!