# Numpy matrix row/column memory layout

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

Numpy nd-arrays are laid out as contiguous 1-d arrays.

This stack overflow conversation ([Copying bytes in Python from Numpy array into string or bytearray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341785/copying-bytes-in-python-from-numpy-array-into-string-or-bytearray)) suggests that row indexing of matrices are 'views' into the original array, and that no new array objects allocated in memory when indexing.

However, I'm getting weird results when I look at address locations of individual rows of a numpy matrix. For example,

```
>> x = numpy.random.rand(2,2)
>> x.data
   <read-write buffer for 0x7fdc92a941c0, size 32, offset 0 at 0x7fdc92ad2d30>
>> x[0,].data
   <read-write buffer for 0x7fdc92a94a30, size 16, offset 0 at 0x7fdc929e7270>
>> x[1,].data
   <read-write buffer for 0x7fdc92a94080, size 16, offset 0 at 0x7fdc929e7030>
```

Using GDB, I found that the distance between the addresses of `x[0,]` and `x[1,]` was 576 bytes and the distance between the addresses of `x[0,]` and `x` was 965312 bytes:

```
>> (gdb) print 0x7fdc929e7030 - 0x7fdc929e7270
$1 = -576
>> (gdb) print 0x7fdc92ad2d30 - 0x7fdc929e7270
$2 = 965312
```

If no new array objects are created when indexing the rows of matrix `x`, why are these array views so far apart in memory? Does the distance between array views in memory destroy the cache performance of matrix operations that operate across rows/columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.__array_interface__` gives a nicer display than `.data`.

```
In [498]: x=np.random.rand(2,2)
In [499]: x.__array_interface__['data']
Out[499]: (182019952, False)
In [500]: x[0].__array_interface__['data']
Out[500]: (182019952, False)
In [501]: x[0,:].__array_interface__['data']
Out[501]: (182019952, False)
In [502]: x[1,:].__array_interface__['data']
Out[502]: (182019968, False)
```

These addresses are all the same or nearby.

Selecting a single item will produce a different address.

```
In [504]: x[0,0].__array_interface__['data']
Out[504]: (182020568, False)
```

This isn't a view, it's a `np.float64`.

Answer (score 1):

The `at 0x7fdc92ad2d30` bit doesn't indicate where the storage for the buffer's contents is located. It indicates where the buffer object header is located - the little thing with a bunch of metadata and a pointer to the buffer's contents. The location of the buffer header is completely independent of the location of its contents.

As an example, since `x.data` is generated on the fly, the `at 0xwherever` bit can say something completely different on each access:

```
In [7]: x = numpy.arange(8)

In [8]: x.data
Out[8]: <read-write buffer for 0x24a6b60, size 64, offset 0 at 0x7f3a7b3438f0>

In [9]: x.data
Out[9]: <read-write buffer for 0x24a6b60, size 64, offset 0 at 0x7f3a7b343970>
```